# python: Piping a value through an if/elif statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a function that can return one of three values: a, b, or c.

```
def f():
    return x # a, b, or c
```

I need to execute different statements based on the return value of `f()`: A, B, or C. The best way to do this, that I know of, is:

```
v = f()
if v == a:
    # Do A
elif v == b:
    # Do B
else:
    # Do C
```

Without introducing this new variable `v`, is there a different way to evaluate the return value of `f()`?
Something like this, maybe?

```
if f() == a:
    # Do A
elif _value_from_above == b:
    # Do B
else:
    # Do C
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's wrong with creating the temporary variable?

Comment: @darthbith I'm trying to minimize the amount of variables I create. I guess, more of a personal preference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not what you want, but one option is to use a dictionary of functions:

```
def do_a();
    ..
def do_b();
    ..
def do_c();
    ..

strategy = {
    a: do_a,
    b: do_b
    c: do_c
}

strategy[f()]()
```

But normally you'd want some error handling in case the dictionary entry wasn't found, in which case you'd likely end up with a separate variable anyway, plus you now have to extract each case into its own function.

Maybe even less relevant, if there are only two cases you can use a ternary operator:

```
do_a() if f() == a else do_b()
```

Though likely you already know this, plus your question has more than two cases, plus lots of people don't like the ternary operator, but anyway.

If you have a language with a switch statement, like C#/Java/C++ etc, or a pattern matching statement, like any of Haskell/OCaml/F#/Scala/Erlang etc, then you can use those. A pattern matching statement looks like this:

```
match f() with
| a ->
    // do something
    // and maybe something else too
| b ->
    // do some other thing
    // and yet some other thing
```

but there is no such feature in Python.

Comment: An `if else` block is designed to conditionally **execute code**.  The ternary operator is designed to conditionally **evaluate to a value**.  I'm pretty sure the people who have issues with the ternary operator just dislike it when people use it to execute one statement or the other since that is what the `if else` statements are for.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen you're right that the way I've used it above is  awful, but lots of people seem to have a problem even when it is used to evaluate to a value. Ideally I prefer using as many pure functions as possible and only "doing" something (changing state) when absolutely necessary

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this with if/elif and Python (before 3.11) does not have a switch statement. You need the temporary variable.

You can alternatively use a dispatch table if you know the exact values of a, b, and c. It's a little more verbose, but if you have a lot of possible branches, it will be faster and possibly easier to follow.

To make a dispatch table:

- Make a function for each branch
- Make a dictionary that maps a, b, c to their corresponding function
- Replace all of that code with `return DISPATCH_TABLE[f()]()`

You can find some examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to map answers (without computing further), then you can solve it with a simple mapping function (similar to junichiro's answer):

```
import random

def f():
    foo = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    return random.choice(foo)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from_to = dict(a=2, b=1, c=3, d=4, e=5)
    print(from_to.get(f(), None))
```

In case you have an unforeseen value from `f()` then `from_to.get(f(), None)` would default to `None`